# New DateTime instead of String in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I've got some issue with DateTime in Ruby
I've got line which looks like this (it's in .txt file)

```
DateTime.new(1979,1,1) DateTime.new(2012,3,29)
```

And my function to get this looks like this

```
def split_line
  array = line.split(' ')
  @date_of_birth = array[0] 
  @date_of_death = array[1] 
end
```

But `@date_of_birth` and `@date_of_death` class are String. How can I get them as DateTime?

Comment: Are you passing the line into the function? Currently line would be undefined

Comment: You have a string `"DateTime.new(1979,1,1) DateTime.new(2012,3,29)"`? Why?

Comment: This could well be an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)". WHY do you have that line in a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string is in the correct format, then you're probably looking for:

```
@date_of_birth = array[0].to_datetime
@date_of_death = array[1].to_datetime
```

See here for more info:

https://apidock.com/rails/String/to_datetime

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
DateTime.new(1979,1,1) DateTime.new(2012,3,29)
```

Is not code. What do you expect that to do?

If you want two `DateTimes` as a space-separated string, do something like:

```
"#{DateTime.new(1979,1,1)} #{DateTime.new(2012,3,29)}"
```

When you have something like `#{...}` inside a set of double quotation marks (they **must** be double, not single quotation marks), it's called `string interpolation`. Learn it. Love it. Live it.

But, for the life of me, I don't know why you wouldn't do:

```
[DateTime.new(1979,1,1), DateTime.new(2012,3,29)]
```

Which gives you an `array`, so no `split` needed. Just:

```
def split_line
  @date_of_birth = array[0] 
  @date_of_death = array[1] 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want DateTime values, grab the numbers and create them:

```
require 'date'

'DateTime.new(1979,1,1) DateTime.new(2012,3,29)'.split.map { |s|
  DateTime.new(*s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) )
}
# => [#<DateTime: 1979-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2443875j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
#     #<DateTime: 2012-03-29T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456016j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

The values aren't DateTime though, they're Dates:

```
'DateTime.new(1979,1,1) DateTime.new(2012,3,29)'.split.map { |s|
  Date.new(*s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) )
}
# => [#<Date: 1979-01-01 ((2443875j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
#     #<Date: 2012-03-29 ((2456016j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

Breaking it down:

```
'DateTime.new(1979,1,1) DateTime.new(2012,3,29)'.split # => ["DateTime.new(1979,1,1)", "DateTime.new(2012,3,29)"]
  .map { |s|
  Date.new(
    *s.scan(/\d+/) # => ["1979", "1", "1"], ["2012", "3", "29"]
    .map(&:to_i) # => [1979, 1, 1],       [2012, 3, 29]
  )
}
# => [#<Date: 1979-01-01 ((2443875j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
#     #<Date: 2012-03-29 ((2456016j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

`*` (AKA "splat"), used like this, explodes an array into its elements, which is useful when you have an array but the method only takes separate parameters.

The bigger question is why you're getting values like that in a text file.